# Set mat-menu style

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material2

Im having alot of trouble with this, and the apparent solutions aren't working or im doing something wrong (probably the latter).

I want to style my `mat-menu` and the `mat-menu-item`'s, ive tried doing this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu{
  background-color:red;
}
```

But it doesnt work, my menu looks like this (nothing abornomal)

```
<mat-menu #infoMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Resume</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
    <span>Portfolio</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>References</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
    <span>Contact</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

I have also tried /deep/ but I know that shouldn't work and in fact should be depreciated in Angular 4 but I did it to test, I am not sure how to style the elements at this point.

Comment: `.mat-menu-panel` might help, as well as using `ViewEncapsulation.None`

Comment: the panel call sadly doesnt do anything, and im not sure where I would set that viewencapsulation to none? D:

Comment: I'll go ahead and write up a more detailed answer for ya

Comment: I had to edit the answer to make it clear that your root component controls the `mat-menu` and needs to control the `encapsulation`.

Comment: I got it working, just wondering, this viewencapsulation setting, will it affect the children called in the html file, or just the file itself

Comment: Cleanest way to do this is having a custom theme scss and add your css rules for .mat-menu in there. Check out https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/05/23/custom-themes-with-angular-material.htm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation ... } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

**my.component.css**

```
.mat-menu-content {
    background-color: 'red' !important;
}
```

I typically use this to style the height and overflow css, but the general idea should still stand for background-color. Please note that there may be other overlaying divs with background-colors, but you should be able to access them in this way by their `.mat-menu-<item name>` css and change children items in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was just wondering how to also edit the fade color, it starts at the 'default' grey color and fades into the custom color I set like how you showed, is that just trial and error? Im not asking because im trying to imply youre wrong just wondered if you knew, thanks for this brilliant solution!

Comment: Update 2: I really need to say thanks again, this fix is allowing me to finally customize everything in Material 2 easily and effectively!! <3

Comment: Update 3: This caused very strange problems in rendering on Mobile browsers (the enabling of encapsulation that is) so be aware!

Comment: @Cacoon This answer is now deprecated, since they have added an input directive to directly inject whatever class you'd like: `@Input('class')
panelClass: string` https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api

Comment: Awesome, material keeps making great progress

Comment: Note that `ViewEncapsulation.None` will affect **all** `mat-menu-content` in the entire application.

Comment: Though the answer may be near six year old , it is still good for me.   anything to avoid ngdeep

Answer (score 42):

**Easier Way**
If you want to change your component only without affecting other components, you should add a class to the menu.

```
<mat-menu #infoMenu="matMenu" class="customize"></mat-menu>
```

Then style your menu with ::ng-deep.

```
::ng-deep .customize {
  background: red;
}
```

voila!! your customization will not affect other components.

**Another Way:**
you can add backdropClass to the menu.

```
 <mat-menu #infoMenu="matMenu" backdropClass="customize"></mat-menu>
```

Then add CSS style class with +*  in your styles.css

```
.customize+* .mat-menu-panel {
  background: red;
}
```

This is also accomplished without affecting others, but adding css in styles.css may be a bit inconvenient.

Comment: the second way seems to be good one .. as `ng-deep` is deprecated

Comment: `<mat-menu [class]="'customize'"></mat-menu>` and `::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel.constrast { background: red; }` did it for me

Answer (score 11):

Define original `background-color` and `mouseover` color both in the CSS:

```
.mat-menu-item {
  color: blue !important;
}

button.mat-menu-item{
    background-color: white;
}

button.mat-menu-item:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks. Dear user avoid using !important.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution which (1) allows us to keep our default ViewEncapsulation and (2) does not require the deprecated ::ng-deep

**app.component.html**

```
<mat-menu #infoMenu="matMenu" class="my-class">...
```

And then in your global styles sheet

**styles.css**

```
.mat-menu-panel.my-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

This solution was provided in the Angular/Components git repository: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16742

The original author of this solution provided a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y3jqzt

Comment: Pretty sure this is the best answer to the original question.  ::ng-deep is bad, !important is bad and changing how you configure your component just to get a style to work is bad.  This solution works and avoids all the bad stuff.

Comment: Mostly agree with David's comment. basically the reason for having to do this is that the CDK overlay is at the top level of the DOM, and the menu is rendered inside the CDK overlay

Answer (score 1):

Since ::ng-deep is deprecated, this is how I customize `mat-menu`

```html
<mat-menu class="user-menu" #menu="matMenu">
   <button mat-menu-item>Profile</button>
   <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button>
</mat-menu>
```

In the new version of Angular Material, I used the base class of `mat-menu`, which is `mat-mdc-menu-panel`

```css
.mat-mdc-menu-panel.user-menu {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to require disabling view encapsulation? Because I can't get it to work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I customized angular material element `mat-menu` by using `::ng-deep`

```
<mat-menu #createPlan="matMenu" class="custom-menu">
    <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="profilestypes">Client Profile</button>
          <button mat-menu-item>Supplier Profile</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Advisor Profile</button>
</mat-menu>
```

while css class was as follows

```
::ng-deep .custom-menu{
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

and it got applied to each and every internal class of mat-menu