# What is another alternative to angular ::ng-deep other than changing the global stylesheet and changing the encapsulation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change the sc-menu background color using a "custom" class. I don't want to use the global stylesheet and change the encapsulation to None. At the moment, the encapsulation is shadowDom.

I tried using  `:host ::ng-deep .custom`, but the background color does not change. Is there any other alternative other than using a global stylesheet or changing the encapsulation?

I created an example on stackblitz to demonstrate what I am doing which can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frkkkv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmenu%2Fmenu.component.scss)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set mat-menu style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821027/set-mat-menu-style)

Comment: Hi Matthieu, thanks. When I tried the ::ng-deep customize, it did not work. And the encapsulation.None option, I don't want to use it because the styles will leak into other components.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with mat-menu is that the panel does not belong to your component in DOM, it is placed in `<div class="cdk-overlay-container"></div>`. Therefore `:host` can't target it. I believe there is no way to keep styles affecting this panel scoped to the parent component, as the panel is actually outside of it.

You can still pass the custom class to mat-menu and then modify it in global CSS so only it gets affected if you don't find another solution.

Code to add in global CSS:

```
.mat-menu-panel.custom {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi Miloš, thanks. I currently don't have access to a the global stylesheet so that's why I don't want to use that alternative.